# Can't mount RAID after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, raid, software-raid, kubuntu

I just upgraded my box to 14.04 and on bootup I got a message, that my RAID devices can't be mounted automatically so I chose to skip it and work through it after boot time. Now booted up, A mount -a gives me:

```
$ sudo mount -a
[sudo] password for reg: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

$
```

while my mdadm.conf looks like:

```
$ cat /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# next line added by reg 09/01/2009
ARRAY /dev/md0 devices=/dev/sdb6,/dev/sdc6
ARRAY /dev/md1 devices=/dev/sdb7,/dev/sdc7
#ARRAY /dev/md2 devices=/dev/sdb8,/dev/sdc8

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This file was auto-generated on Tue, 08 May 2012 18:26:22 -0700
# by mkconf $Id$
$
```

just quickly started gparted to check if all my dirves show up and fair enough, my partitions 6 & 7 show up just fine on drives sdb and sdc.
Also, seems like mdadm is running just fine:

```
$ ps ax | grep mdadm
 1945 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --pid-file /run/mdadm/monitor.pid --daemonise --scan --syslog
 7869 pts/8    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mdadm
$
```

what could be my problem here, I don't quite follow.

```
$ dmesg | tail
[ 1437.716819] EXT4-fs (md0): bad geometry: block count 61034935 exceeds size of device (61034912 blocks)
[ 1437.717197] EXT4-fs (md1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 1437.717422] EXT4-fs (md1): bad geometry: block count 59585077 exceeds size of device (59585056 blocks)
[ 3030.508560] init: nvidia-persistenced main process (21110) terminated with status 1
[ 3757.003367] current rate 16719823 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[ 3757.006356] current rate 10357448 is different from the runtime rate 48000
[ 3850.605129] EXT4-fs (md0): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 3850.605299] EXT4-fs (md0): bad geometry: block count 61034935 exceeds size of device (61034912 blocks)
[ 3850.605585] EXT4-fs (md1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[ 3850.605782] EXT4-fs (md1): bad geometry: block count 59585077 exceeds size of device (59585056 blocks)
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$
```

and syslog says nothing but

```
$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md/127_0: No such file or directory
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=0.90 UUID=0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=0.90 UUID=91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$
```

**edit 1**

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb6[1] sdc6[0]
      244139648 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb7[1] sdc7[0]
      238340224 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md127 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sdc3[0]
      390628416 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
$ 

$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
         Events : 0.75007

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6
       1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
         Events : 0.3973383

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
       1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
$ 

$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb6
/dev/sdb6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : bfa701ff - correct
         Events : 75007


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6

   0     0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6
   1     1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb7
/dev/sdb7:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 2a7376fd - correct
         Events : 3973383


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7

   0     0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
   1     1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc6
/dev/sdc6:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 91e560f1:4e51d8eb:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  1 19:15:33 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
     Array Size : 244139648 (232.83 GiB 250.00 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : bfa7020d - correct
         Events : 75007


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6

   0     0       8       38        0      active sync   /dev/sdc6
   1     1       8       22        1      active sync   /dev/sdb6
reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc7
/dev/sdc7:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 0abe503f:401d8d09:cd707cc0:bc3f8165
  Creation Time : Tue Sep  8 21:19:15 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
     Array Size : 238340224 (227.30 GiB 244.06 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 1

    Update Time : Sun May  4 21:32:24 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : 2a73770b - correct
         Events : 3973383


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7

   0     0       8       39        0      active sync   /dev/sdc7
   1     1       8       23        1      active sync   /dev/sdb7
$ 

$ sudo parted /dev/sdb unit mib print free
Model: ATA ST31000528AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 953870MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start      End        Size       Type      File system     Flags
 1      0.03MiB    95370MiB   95370MiB   primary   ext4            boot
 3      95370MiB   476843MiB  381473MiB  primary   ext4
 2      476843MiB  953859MiB  477016MiB  extended
 6      476843MiB  715261MiB  238418MiB  logical   ext3
 7      715261MiB  948015MiB  232754MiB  logical   ext3
 5      948015MiB  953859MiB  5844MiB    logical   linux-swap(v1)
        953859MiB  953870MiB  10.3MiB              Free Space

reg@regDesktopHome:~/semios$ sudo parted /dev/sdc unit mib print free
Model: ATA ST31000528AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 953870MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start      End        Size       Type      File system     Flags
 1      0.03MiB    95370MiB   95370MiB   primary   ext4            boot
 3      95370MiB   476843MiB  381473MiB  primary   ext4
 2      476843MiB  953859MiB  477016MiB  extended
 6      476843MiB  715261MiB  238418MiB  logical   ext3
 7      715261MiB  948015MiB  232754MiB  logical   ext3
 5      948015MiB  953859MiB  5844MiB    logical   linux-swap(v1)
        953859MiB  953870MiB  10.3MiB              Free Space

$
```

**edit 2**

I tried the suggested but my file system wouldn't mount:

```
# sudo losetup --find --show --read-only /dev/sdc7 /dev/loop0
# mount -o ro /dev/loop0 /mnt/loop0 mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'
#
```

**edit 3**
`file -s /dev/loop0` returns me the following:

```
$ sudo file -s /dev/loop0
[sudo] password for reg: 
/dev/loop0: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=b2d66029-eeb9-4e4a-952c-0a3bd0696159 (large files)
```

Comment: need a lot more info. `/proc/mdstat`, `mdadm --detail /dev/md?`, `mdadm --examine /dev/sdx?`, `parted /dev/sdx unit mib print free`, ...

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks for your reply! I added some more info above under **edit 1**

Answer (score 3):

> bad geometry: block count 61034935 exceeds size of device (61034912 blocks)

According to these error messages, it seems your RAID shrank by a few blocks; which is an unusual problem considering that `0.90` metadata is at the end, and `ext3` metadata is at the beginning of a partition, so the partition size itself cannot have changed, as such a change on either end would lead to missing metadata.

I can't imagine how this happened; in order to break things this way intentionally, you'd have to do something like running `resize2fs` on the member disks instead of the RAID itself; or start out without RAID and add it only as an afterthought.

Since it's `RAID1` and the raid metadata is at the end of the disk, you should be able to mount either disk directly. A simple way to test this would be with a read-only loop device. Provided the filesystem does not have a defective/dirty superblock as well, this should do:

```
# losetup --find --show --read-only /dev/sdc7
/dev/loop4
# mount -o ro /dev/loop4 /mnt/test
```

If that works and the files are intact, it would be a good time to backup.

If the filesystem requires `fsck` as well, the safest way to do so is to make a copy of the entire partition with `dd` and then `fsck` the image.

```
# dd if=/dev/sdc7 of=/mnt/ext/sdc7.img bs=1M
# losetup --find --show /mnt/ext/sdc7.img
/dev/loop5
# fsck /dev/loop5
# mount /dev/loop5 /mnt/test
```

If that works, you might be able to fix your RAID in place using these steps:

1. remove the other drive:

   ```
   # mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb7
   # mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdb7
   ```
2. fix and resize the filesystem on the remaining drive. block size taken from the error message you provided

   ```
   # fsck /dev/sdc7
   # resize2fs /dev/sdc7 61034912
   # sync
   ```
3. test if it worked

   ```
   # echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
   # mount /dev/md0 /mnt/somewhere
   ```
4. readd and resync the other drive

   ```
   # mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb7
   ```

However, you might consider re-creating the RAID from scratch with current metadata (`1.2`) and remaking the filesystem and copying the files back onto it instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately my partition wouldn't mount, please see **edit 2** above. Thanks!

Comment: @cerr, `mount` might refuse to mount raid members because normally, you should be mounting the raid itself instead. if `file -s /dev/loop0` says it's a filesystem, try adding `-t fstype`.

Comment: please see **edit3** above. Thanks!